# Compare a string to a string an array ignoring the case

Tags: python, arrays, string, comparison

I am wanting to compare a string called `itemToReplace` to one in an array but ignoring the case (if it's a capital letter or lower case).

Here is the code:

```
itemToReplace = input("Choose an item to replace: ")
if itemToReplace in self._inventory:
    # do something...
```

And when I do this, if the user types in something like `"sWord"` instead of `"Sword"`, it won't work. So does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: simply add either `.upper()` or `.lower()` to the end of the input and it will change the case so you can deal with it easier

Comment: Do you want to ignore the case and other extra capitalized letters in the string? If so, then use .lower() method on the string you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help.

```
import string
print 'sWord'.lower() in map(string.lower, ['Sword'])
```

**Output:**

```
True
```

1. Convert the input to lower case
2. use `map` method to convert all string elements in list to lower and the use `in` .

Comment: he needs to change the case of a single string input, not a list.. Ideal for a list but a little too much for a single string..of course if the `_inventory` is full of mixed case strings then this will be ideal!

Answer (score 0):

Change the case of the entire input by doing.

```
itemToReplace = input("Choose an item to replace: ").upper() #Uppercase
```

or

```
itemToReplace = input("Choose an item to replace: ").lower() #Lowercase
```